# Prove that a system is hyperbolic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This question is from Teschl ODE and dynamical systems. Problem 9.2

Let $A$ be a real-valued two by two matrix and let

$$χ_A (z) = z^2 − T z + D = 0,$$

$T = tr(A)$, $D = \det(A)$,
be its characteristic polynomial. Show that A is hyperbolic if $T D \neq 0$. Moreover, $A$ is asymptotically stable if and only if $D > 0$ and $T < 0$. (Hint:
$T = α_1 + α_2$ , $D = α_1 α_2 $.)

Let $A$ be a real-valued three by three matrix and let
$$χ_A (z) = z^3 − T z^2 + M z − D = 0 $$

be its characteristic polynomial. Show that $A$ is hyperbolic if $(T M − D)D \neq 0$. Moreover, $A$ is asymptotically stable if and only if $D < 0$, $T < 0$ and
$T M < D$. (Hint: $T = α_1 + α_2 + α_3 , M = α _1 α_2 + α_2 α_3 + α_2 α_3 , D = α_1 α_2 α_3 ,
and $T M − D = (α_1 + α_2 )(α_1 + α_3 )(α_2 + α_3 )$ .)

I know how to get the stability part but i tried investigating $ b^2 - 4ac $ for the hyperbolic part but i cant seem to get it. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Show that if $A$ is non-hyperbolic, then $(TM-D)D = 0$. This proves that if $(TM-D)D \neq 0$, matrix $A$ can't be non-hyperbolic, because all non-hyperbolic matrices have $(TM-D)D = 0$. To prove that $(TM-D)D = 0$ for non-hyperbolic matrix, describe all variants how $A$ could be non-hyperbolic and compute $(TM-D)D$ for all of them.

Comment: can i use the routh hurwitz criterion?

Comment: Sure, you can use Routh-Hurwits criterion for figuring out stability. It won't help with other stuff.